# add_rewrite_rule working in parent theme but not in child theme

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I have created a CPT and created add rewrite rule using the following code to achieve the following URL structure:

https://www.example.com/coupons/company/

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() 
{
    add_rewrite_rule('^coupons/([a-z0-9-]+)[/]?$', 'coupons/?host=$1', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');

add_action( 'template_include', function( $template ) {
    if ( get_query_var( 'host' ) == false || get_query_var( 'host' ) == '' ) {
        return $template;
    }
 
    return  get_theme_file_path().'/list-coupons.php';
} );
```

I have placed the above code in functions.php of child theme but I get a 404 error. The same code worked when successfully when I had uploaded this code in functions.php file of parent theme.

Note: list-coupons.php file exists as a custom template in child theme.

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress's `get_query_var()` function just retrieves just the values of its native query variables in the WP_Query class.

Thus, before your `add_action( 'template_include'...` you will have to add your custom query variable `'host'` manually to the array of public query variables like [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/#custom-query-vars):

```
function themeslug_query_vars( $qvars ) {
    $qvars[] = 'host';
    return $qvars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'themeslug_query_vars' );
```

This condition has always been `true`:

```
if ( ... || get_query_var( 'host' ) == '' ) {
 return $template;
}
```

And so you always got the default template path in return.
Which produced the `404`, when placing your code in child theme's `functions.php`.

Because that default template can just be found at the returned path inside the parent theme.